# Can I animate absolute positioned element with CSS transition?

Tags: css, css-transitions

I want to animate an element's position change with CSS transition, but it is not working even when I use the transition on `all` properties, as in the example here: http://jsfiddle.net/yFy5n/3/

However, I don't want my final solution to apply transition to all properties, but instead only on the position change. So the color change should be instant, only the position change from left to right should be animated (the opposite of what is happening now).

Comment: Since no one mentioned it: the `left` property defaults to `auto`. Transitions will never work if one of the start or end points is that value. Both have to be defined. The reason why the margin solution in the answer below works is because all four sides of the margin default to `0`, so it has that defined value set already.

Comment: @animuson Yup. Someone cleared all the comments, but you can see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24973176/can-i-animate-absolute-positioned-element-with-css-transition#comment38819970_24973194) that the original OPs version worked on an earlier version of Chrome, pretty weird.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

You forgot to define the default value for `left` so it doesn't know how to animate.

```
.test {
    left: 0;
    transition:left 1s linear;
}
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/shomz/yFy5n/5/

Comment: For more compatibility you can use JS $('#test').animate({'left': 60 });

Comment: @Shomz: Thanks mate. Not sure how it is working for me (?!). I am on Chrome v24 with Windows

Comment: Thank you (i expected it to assume the default left, so i never thought to define it myself); however, what change should i do to get only the position to transition, not the color?

Comment: @Harry Yeah, funny thing. I'm on Chrome v36. Just tried Chromium and nothing. Sounds like they are handling initial values differently.

Comment: @ImNotMike You're welcome. To narrow it down, just set `left` instead of `all`: http://jsfiddle.net/shomz/yFy5n/14/

Answer (score 7):

Please Try this code `margin-left:60px` instead of `left:60px`

please take a look: [http://jsfiddle.net/hbirjand/2LtBh/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/hbirjand/2LtBh/)

as @Shomz said,transition must be changed to `transition:margin 1s linear;` instead of `transition:all 1s linear;`

Comment: Not sure why someone downvoted this. It avoids the `left` bug just fine. +1 from me. Btw. since OP want only position shift, transition can be modified to `margin`: http://jsfiddle.net/shomz/2LtBh/1/

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
.test {
    position:absolute;
    background:blue;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    top:40px;
    transition:left 1s linear;
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you expand a little on why "this" is going to work? That will make this answer useful for someone else in the future with a problem that is similar but not exactly the same.