# Is there any way to implement a box animation in CSS?

Tags: css

While doing a project, I need to draw a box which plays animation within 2 second and will move one corner to another.How can I do It in a easy way?

Comment: How to ask good question? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Try something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24973176/can-i-animate-absolute-positioned-element-with-css-transition

Comment: You may use translateX https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translateX

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of doing animations and it will be worth reading up on both CSS transition and CSS animation.

Just to start off here is a very simple example. A red square sits in a container whose dimensions are known. The square has a transition of 2s set on all - which means on any animatable CSS property.

When you click the button it has a class added or removed (using toggle) and in this the square is translated to the bottom of the container (or back to its initial position when the class is removed).

```css
.container {
  border: solid 1px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
}

.box {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 2s;
  display: inline-block;
}

.box.move {
  transform: translate(240px, 90px)
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
<button onclick="document.querySelector('.box').classList.toggle('move');">click me</button>`enter code here`
```